# Artifacts for ASP.NET MVC project in GITLAB

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment, azure-web-app-service, artifacts

I have a asp.net mvc project, which is already there in GitLab repository.

I have configured a specific windows runner for my project.
I have installed visual studio in the runner machine.
Now I am able to build my code whenever pipeline runs.

I want to create an artifact package and use to deploy to my azure app service in next stage in pipelne.

How to create the artifact after build, and where these artifacts getting stored (runner machine or git repo)?

Also It would be great if someone can help with script to web deploy (instaed of FTP) the app service in deploy stage

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Naresh Ede.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi please see my comment in answers section. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have written the YAML file like below to build and generate artifacts.
The solution build was successful when i'm seeing the log, but getting a warning at generating artifacts

```js
stages:
- build

solution-build:
stage: build
script:
    -   MSBuild.exe 'my-awesome-app.sln' /p:OutputPath="c:\Builds\awesome- 
project"
artifacts:
    paths:
        - artifacts/
```

Job Log:

Uploading artifacts...
108 Runtime platform                                    arch=386 os=windows pid=19556 revision=577f813d version=12.5.0
109 WARNING: binaries/: no matching files
110 ERROR: No files to upload